# Storing Article titles from newsapi into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, api

I am pretty new to programming, originally I am a graphic designer, so apologies if my question seems stupid. 
I'm trying to make something with the newsapi, basically I want to display article titles. I got to that part alright, but now I would want to store the articles titles in an array to be able to get back to it.

I tried almost everything and I can't seem to get it to work. I tried to define the array before the function as

```
    var allTitles = [];
```

and then tried to fill it with the values pulled from the API

```
    var allTitles = articleTitle[I];
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is the whole code.
Thanks a lot for your help!

```
r input = document.getElementById('input');
var container = document.getElementById('container');

var allTitles = [];
function getNews(event) {

if (event.keyCode == 13) {


    var everything = $.get("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=" + input.value + "&language=en&apiKey=612c24355bc24dbcbb4b13496d772971");


        everything.done(function(data) {


            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {




                    // var articleImageHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250) + 150;
                    var articleContainer = document.createElement('DIV');
                    var articleTitle = document.createElement('a');
                    var articleDescription = document.createElement('p');
                    articleContainer.classList.add('article-container');
                    articleTitle.classList.add('article-title');
                    articleDescription.classList.add('article-description');
                    container.appendChild(articleContainer);
                    articleContainer.appendChild(articleTitle);
                    articleContainer.appendChild(articleDescription);
                    articleTitle.innerHTML = data.articles[i].title;
                    articleTitle.setAttribute('href', data.articles[i].url);
                    articleTitle.setAttribute('target', '_blank');


                    var allTitles = articleTitle[i];


                    }

        });

    input.value = "";

    while (container.firstChild) {
        container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
    }

}

}

input.addEventListener('keyup', getNews);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest of your code is working as intended, the article title will be made available in `data.articles[i].title`, so to store it in the array `allTitles` you just need to replace this line:

```
var allTitles = articleTitle[i];
```

With this (see MDN article on [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)):

```
allTitles.push(data.articles[i].title);
```

Or alternatively:

```
allTitles[i] = data.articles[i].title;
```

Comment: Oooh got it, was not familiar with the push method. Thanks a lot! :)